# Fail to write the reduce method using Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

```
@Getter
public class Dish {
   BigDecimal price;
}
```

I need to calculate the **total price of all ordered dishes**, but I fail to write the reduce method.
This is a  method signature ( argument has a map of Dish and how many times it was ordered ).

So it must be something like this  `sum of every dish.getPrice * dishQuantaty`

```
    private BigDecimal getOrderTotalPrice(Map<Dish, Integer> dishQuantityMap) {
}
```

The fail-code I was asked about

```
  return   dishQuantityMap.entrySet().stream()
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,
                (dishIntegerEntry) ->
               dishIntegerEntry.getKey().getPrice()
                        .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(dishIntegerEntry.getValue())));
```

Comment: @RealSkeptic I've spend pretty much an hour trying to solve it myself, fail attempt code must be unrelated for such a simple code.

Comment: Show the code you tried to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
private BigDecimal getOrderTotalPrice(Map<Dish, Integer> dishQuantityMap) {
  return dishQuantityMap.entrySet().stream()
          .map(d -> d.getKey().getPrice().multiply(new BigDecimal(d.getValue())))
          .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
}
```